# Why doesn't `2>&1` work in this pipeline?

Tags: shell, redirection, pipe

I can't find a way to redirect error on my NAS.

The shell is `/bin/sh` and when I use `> mylogfile.log 2>&1` I still see the error printing on the terminal. The specific command is

```
find /volume1/ | grep "totoro" > ~/totoro.log 2>&1
```

and I see error from `find`. Any way to make the redirection working? How to write `find` errors in the log file?

Comment: `find /volume1/ | grep "totoro" > ~/totoro.log 2>&1`

Comment: no error from grep, how to write `find` errors in the log file?

Comment: Note that you don't need `grep`: you can use `find`'s own  `-name` or `-path` option. In your case the equivalent command would be `find /volume1/ -path "totoro" > ~/totoro.log 2>&1`, assuming you want both the errors and matching file names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> find /volume1/ | grep "totoro" > ~/totoro.log 2>&1
> ```

Your `2>&1` affects `grep` only, not `find`. In the below command the first `2>&1` affects `find`:

```
find /volume1/ 2>&1 | grep "totoro" > ~/totoro.log 2>&1   # probably wrong
```

But this will send stderr along with stdout from `find` to `grep`. You probably don't want `grep` to filter stderr from `find`. I guess you want to capture stdout and stderr of the entire composed command. If so, run the command in an explicit subshell and redirect its output and error streams:

```
(find /volume1/ 2>&1 | grep "totoro") > ~/totoro.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the "tee" command. It reads from standard input and writes to standard output and files. This can be helpful here.